Is here a mistake or can you explain me what orthonormal basis mean?
I am currently trying to get insight into SVD, and I found one book with an explanation of how we find the  and  matrices and why it holds that any × matrix can be represented in this particular way. However, I encountered this confusing explanation:
the image is here (have not enough reputation to embed pictures directly into the post)
Here, we have an orthonormal basis of  vectors _ (they are eigenvectors of symmetric matrix ATA (A transpose * A)), so due to spectral theorem each has a length of 1, and they are all orthogonal to each other. But my question is, why does it say that the set of vectors _ is also orthonormal if, in fact, each has a length of square root of _, which is not always equal to 1? Is this a mistake in the book, or am I missing something?
(Sorry, it's my first time asking a question here, so I don't know how to add proper characters)

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

In your convention they manifestly mean orthogonal, and possibly they have restricted the discussion to the $v_i$-s that are not in $\ker A$.
